# Who has created Trimurti? Adishakthi or Brahman?

Tags: vedas, brahman, durga

In my childhood, I heard a myth that Goddess [Adishakthi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Parashakti) created Shiva, Brahma and Vishnu (I am familiar with this myth).  But now I am listening new myth such as [Brahman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman) is the one who made Shiva, Brahma and Vishnu.

- Which one of them is true? or have I misunderstood?
- How were Trimurti (Brahma, Shiva and Vishnu) formed?

Comment: There is no difference between Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesvara. There is no difference between Siva and Shakti. There is no difference at all. Brahman, Shiva, Shakti, Vishnu, are all just various names of God !! No-one has created the other. The various stories of creation such as Adishakti created the Trimurti, Vishnu created the trimurthi, Shiva appeared as Jyothirlinga, are all just various ways of saying the same thing. How Trimurti were formed? They were formed by their devotees. God assumes various roles for the purpose of His devotees. God is Himself formless and Absolute!!

Comment: It depends. Are you an Advaitin, Vishishtadvaitin, or Dvaitin? Different denominations of Hinduism will have different views.